# What image formats are accepted by TensorFlow? I have a plt.image.AxesImage, which I want to convert to an image without saving, for a training set

Tags: python, tensorflow, matplotlib, python-imaging-library

I have a matplotlib.image.AxesImage plot like this:
[matplotlib.image.AxesImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u6Q5R.png)

I'm working on a machine learning project for image processing so will need to process thousands of plots like this, retain their information without saving the image file, and then pass it through the training algorithm. I am using TensorFlow. TensorFlow accepts PIL images so I'm trying to find a way to convert this sample matplotlib.image.AxesImage object into a PIL image but all the other guides I found on stackexchange don't quite work. I have inserted some useful code from my project below:

```
image = cv2.imread('test.jpg',0) 
mask = np.zeros(image.shape[:2], dtype="uint8")

circle = cv2.circle(mask, (320,240), 20, 1, 200)
unmasked = np.ma.masked_where(circle == 0, image)

fig_unmasked = plt.imshow(unmasked)
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (600,300)   #change the size of the matplotlib plot
plt.colorbar()

plt.close()
```

My goal is to convert fig_unmasked into a PIL image/or any compatible image object that TensorFlow will accept. I would appreciate any guidance/tips, thank you!

Comment: I would like to suggest you to convert the data into numpy rather than convert it into PIL image.

Comment: Tensorflow image provides Ops to decode and encode JPEG and PNG formats. Encoded images are represented by scalar string Tensors, decoded images by 3-D uint8 tensors of shape `[height, width, channels]`. (PNG also supports uint16.) Fpor details go through tensorflow doc [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image#image_decoding_and_encoding). Thanks!